# Paypal Express checkout refund

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I am trying to allow my website users to click a refund button which will take them to paypal, get them to login, then confirm refund, which then redirects them back to my site. So what i am looking for is the opposite of express checkout. I have looked everywhere but cannot find anything on this.

Does this facility exist or is there a workaround to get the same result?

Thanks

Comment: isent it the account holder what has to login to paypal to authorise refunds?

Comment: Yes just like in express checkout. I just require the same thing for refunds

Comment: but that's buyers, not account holder

Comment: express checkout allows buyers to send sellers money, i'm looking for the opposite

Comment: yes .. but .. ok i give up, good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal doesn't offer a web flow for this; a merchant can simply call the [RefundTransaction](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_RefundTransaction) API call to immediately process a refund.
If you do want some kind of web flow, you'll want to build this yourself.